# regex expression to remove eed from string

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to replace `'eed' and 'eedly' with 'ee'` from words where there is a vowel before either term `('eed' or 'eedly')` appears.

So for example, the word `indeed` would become `indee` because there is a vowel ('i') that happens before the 'eed'. On the other hand the word `'feed'` would not change because there is no vowel before the suffix `'eed'`.

I have this regex: `(?i)([aeiou]([aeiou])*[e{2}][d]|[dly]\\b)`
You can see what is happening with this [here](https://regex101.com/r/lG4qK8/2).

As you can see, this is correctly identifying words that end with `'eed'`, but it is not correctly identifying `'eedly'`.

Also, when it does the replace, it is replacing all words that end with `'eed'` , even words like `feed` which it should not remove the `eed`

What should I be considering here in order to make it correctly identify the words based on the rules I specified?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?i)\\b(\\w*?[aeiou]\\w*)eed(?:ly)?", "$1ee");
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lG4qK8/7)

`\\b(\\w*?[aeiou]\\w*)` before `eed` or `eedly` makes sure there is at least one vowel in the same word before this.

To **expedite** this regex you can use negated expression regex:

```
\\b([^\\Waeiou]*[aeiou]\\w*)eed(?:ly)?
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
\\b                 # word boundary
(                   # start captured group #`
   [^\\Waeiou]*     # match 0 or more of non-vowel and non-word characters
   [aeiou]          # match one vowel
   \\w*             # followed by 0 or more word characters
)                   # end captured group #`
eed                 # followed by literal "eed"
(?:                 # start non-capturing group
   ly               # match literal "ly"
)?                  # end non-capturing group, ? makes it optional
```

Replacement is:

```
"$1ee" which means back reference to captured group #1 followed by "ee"
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you. Would you mind explaining the logic behind this a little more? I am relatively new to regex so I would like to really learn why this is working. @anubhava

Answer (score 1):

find dly before finding d. otherwise your regex evaluation stops after finding eed.

```
(?i)([aeiou]([aeiou])*[e{2}](dly|d))
```